# Unable to show database data as SelectedValue asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to retrieve data out from database and set them as **SelectedValue in dropdownlist and radiobuttonlist**.

The thing is, the data is being retrieved and can be shown when i set as text in label but unable to show in dropdownlist and radiobuttonlist. The coding looks fine to me but nothing is being shown. So i need help to see what when wrong?

texttime and txttime1 can display result but only **ddlEditEventStatus,ddlAddMembershiplist2 and RadioButtonList1.**

CodeBehind:

```
 this.dvUpdate.Visible = true;
                //force databinding
                DataSet ds = dal.getEditEventDetails(promoID);
                this.dvUpdate.DataSource = ds;
                this.dvUpdate.DataBind();

                this.mdlPopup2.Show();

                populatePanelDDL4UpdateEvent(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["membershipType"].ToString());

                //remember the session of the old name
                Session["oldTitle"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["titlePromo"].ToString();

                ((RadioButtonList)dvUpdate.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["defaults"].ToString();

                //set eventCancelledStatus
                //set the time
                //((Label)dvUpdate.FindControl("Label3")).Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["defaults"].ToString();;
                ((DropDownList)dvUpdate.FindControl("ddlEditEventStatus")).SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["promoStatus"].ToString();
                ((DropDownList)dvUpdate.FindControl("ddlAddMembershiplist2")).SelectedValue = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["membershipType"].ToString();

                ((DropDownList)dvUpdate.FindControl("txttime")).Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["startTime"].ToString();
                ((DropDownList)dvUpdate.FindControl("txttime1")).Text = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["endTime"].ToString();
```

Html:

```
  <td class="fields">
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditEventStatus" CssClass="selectMidStyle"  Width="255px" runat="server">
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Opened" Value="Opened"></asp:ListItem>
                                    <asp:ListItem Text="Closed" Value="Closed"></asp:ListItem>
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text">
                                    <asp:Label ID="add_membershipList2" runat="server" Text=" Membership Type : "></asp:Label>
                                </td>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAddMembershiplist2" runat="server" Width="255px"  CssClass="selectMidStyle">

                                    </asp:DropDownList>

                                </td>
                            </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td class="text">
                                    </br>
                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text=" Default Promotion : "></asp:Label>
                                </td>

                                <td>
                                    </br>  
                                 <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server"  ValidationGroup="EditValidationGp">
                                     <asp:ListItem Value="Y">Yes</asp:ListItem>
                                     <asp:ListItem Value="N">No</asp:ListItem>
                                 </asp:RadioButtonList>


                                </td>
```

Comment: Before showing Selected value you have to bind the DropDownList or RadioButtonList. I didn't locate your dropdownlist binding method. So First Bind the DropDownList with proper value then set the SelectedValue for that.

Comment: my dropdownlist listitem were created from database value

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are not finding the required dropdownlist item correctly. Use findbyvalue method like this:

```
 //This is how you set selecteditem
((RadioButtonList)dvUpdate.FindControl("RadioButtonList1")).Items.FindByValue( ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["defaults"].ToString()).Selected=true;
```

Use the same for the other dropdownlists

Answer (score 0):

I figure it out that there are some differences in the database value compared to the values in dropdownlist and radiobuttonlist. Instead nchar, i should set it to nvarchar. Thank you for the comments.